# Find numeric placement of letters

Tags: julia, letter

Looking to find the numeric placement of letters in a random letter vector using a function equivalent to `foo`.

```
myletters = ["a","c","b","d","z"]

foo(myletters)
# [1,3,2,4,26]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: If you're looking for the numeric distance from `'a'`, here's one solution:

```
julia> Int.(first.(["a","c","b","d","z"])) - Int('a') + 1
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  3
  2
  4
 26
```

It will gracefully handle unicode (those simply are later code points and thus will have larger values) and longer strings (by only looking at the first character).  Capitals, numbers, and some symbols will appear as negative numbers since their code points come before `a`.

---

Previous answer: I think you're looking for [`sortperm`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/sort/#Base.sortperm).  It gives you a vector of indices that, if you index back into the original array with it, will put it in sorted order.

```
julia> sortperm(["a","c","b","d"])
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 3
 2
 4
```

Comment: I apologize. My original example was not sufficiently clear. I need to keep the cardinal ordering of the letters. I have updated it.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Are you certain that all your letters are going to be in `'a':'z'`?

Comment: Well, I am thinking an arbitrary mapping solution would be helpful. This is reminding me that there is something about dictionaries I read in the documentation a while ago (`Dict`).

Comment: I like it! Thanks

Comment: You can speed this up by a factor of 4x by adding a couple of dots, and using an array of characters instead of strings: `Int.(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'z']) .- Int('a') .+ 1`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the somewhat convoluted solution:

```
[reshape((1:26)[myletters[i] .== string.('a':'z')],1)[1] for i=1:length(myletters)]
```

Or using `map`

```
map(x -> reshape((1:26)[x .== string.('a':'z')],1)[1], myletters)
```